# Is it dangerous to create a non-temp file in a temp dir?

Tags: python, file, temporary-files

In python I am creating a tempdir (using tempfile.TemporaryDirectory), writing a few text files within it, and then (after processing the files) calling tempdir.cleanup(). The program works, but I'm wondering if there are any dangers to this that aren't immediately visible, especially when working with a large number of files.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I don't understand how the title relates to the question. If you are calling `tempdir.cleanup()` within the same program run, then what "non-temp file" do you have in mind? Did you mean that you are concerned because you create the files "normally" rather than using `tempfile` functionality?

Answer (score 0):

Is it a bad practice? It certainly is. Is it dangerous? Depending on the name, it might get overwritten by another application. Or it might not.

The entire temp folder might be wiped between reboots (linux does this, not sure about windows). Or it might not. The user might delete files in the temp folder to free up space. Or they might not.

Generally, it's just bad practice and don't do it. If your file is non-temporary, then don't put it in the temp folder.